# Android - how to check google play service before start firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I use firebase for push notification

I have a class "MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService"

that start automatically after user start the app

but I want to check 
if google play service is exists and enabled then
 start firebase

else

use another way ...

Manifest :

```
<service
 android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
 <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add this in your android manifest

```
<application>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"     
 />
```

Then to check If Google Playstore exist use this.

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
              googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, status, 2404).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: no man I want check it in manifest level because in api 19 if google play services is not installed on device , the app will force stop !